# How do I select a record based on multiple aliased joins via SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I'm trying to do a join for a record based on permissions where there is at minimum 2 people sharing permissions. 
Note that on one side of the permissions clause, it can be anybody within a set of users.

On the other side, it must match the given id.

So far I have tried doing the following, but it will not return contact records where both user 2702 and 2606 exist:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "contacts".* FROM "contacts"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "permissions" 
    ON "contacts"."id" = "permissions"."contact_id"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "permissions_users" 
    ON "permissions"."id" = "permissions_users"."permission_id"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "permissions_users" "permissions_users_2" 
    ON "permissions"."id" = "permissions_users_2"."permission_id"
  WHERE ("permissions_users"."user_id" IN (2727, 2606, 2729)
    AND "permissions_users_2"."user_id" IN (2702))
    ORDER BY name_sort asc nulls last LIMIT 40 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: Show us some sample data to comprehend what you want to do.

Comment: Currently, your `LEFT JOIN`s are being coerced into `INNER JOIN`s, due to criteria in the `WHERE` clause.  The fact that you aren't getting any results is suggests that there isn't any matching data... And your query may need regular joins anyways.